# From Combination to Permutation

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I am facing a (probably) basic counting issue.
If $P(n,r)$ the permutations for $r$ objects from $n$ and $C(n,r)$ the combinations, we have : $P(n,r) = r!C(n,r)$.

Yet there are two example in which the passage from P to C and the other way around becomes confusing :

**Example 1**

*Task* : From a standard card game of 52 cards, in how many ways can I get 3 different kinds ?

Approach 1. The combinational approach :
Get 3 kinds and get one card from each.

> ${13 \choose 3}{4 \choose 1}^{3}$.

Approach 2. The permutational approach :
Choose one card after the other (removing the suit of the drawn card) and then (as the formula above states) divide by $3!$ since it's a sequence.

> ${52 \choose 1}{48 \choose 1}{44 \choose 1}/3!$

Everything works as the formula states.

**Example 2**

*Task* : From a standard card game of 52 cards, in how many ways can I get a full house ?

Approach 1. The combinational approach :
Get 1 kind and then 3 card from that kind, and then one more kind from which we take 2 more cards.

> ${13 \choose 1}{4 \choose 3}{12 \choose 1}{4 \choose 2}$.

Approach 2. The permutational approach :
Choose two kinds and take 3 from the first and 2 from the second. As we could also take 2 from the first and 3 from the second, the order is relevant = a sequence.

**The problem** : This second approach is a sequence as in example 1, yet instead of dividing (as the formula suggests), I have to *multiply* by 2! to get the right result.

> ${13 \choose 2}{4 \choose 3}{4 \choose 2}\times 2$.

Why ? When do I divide and when do I multiply ?

Comment: Thanks dude! That made it clear. I sadly can't mark a comment as the right answer though.

Comment: Ok, I'll make it an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$P(n,r)=r!C(n,r)$ only works if your are arranging $r$ identical objects from a set of $n$ total. In each of your examples, you are arranging items of different types (3 of one type of card, and 2 of other types, e.g.)

Answer (score 0):

You should divide when you *overcount*, as in example 1) you divide by $3!$ because those three different cards can permute and they do not change the result. However, in example 2) you should multiply by $2!$ because each choice of two different type of cards gives you different result.

Comment: Thanks ! But I still don't understand the difference between two sequences like C(4,3)C(4,2) (example 2) and C(52,1)C(48,1) (example 1). Both are sequences (I think), yet why does one not change the result and the other does?